# mouse controlled by an IMU

Tags: vb.net, mouse, sensors

I am using pitch and yaw angle from an IMU to move a mouse pointer for PC in vb.net. 
Unfortunately it doesn't work steady.

First I set the max angles which should be performed
LOAD-Event

```
 'set max angles in degree
  maxAngle_YawRight = 30
  maxAngle_YawLeft = -30
  maxAngle_PitchUp = 20
  maxAngle_PitchDown = -20
  calculateCurParameter(maxAngle_YawRight, Panel_Right.Location.X, maxAngle_YawLeft, Panel_Left.Location.X + Panel_Left.Width, maxAngle_PitchUp, Panel_Top.Location.Y+Panel_Top.Height, maxAngle_NickDown, Panel_Bottom.Location.Y)
```

I use four these max angles (pitch_up, pitch_down, yaw_right, yaw_left) to assign them to a part of my form, to get 4 points, e.g. (pitch_up,panel_2.location.Y)
pitch_up and pitch_down are used for the y coordinate of the mouse pointer and yaw_right and yaw_left are used for the x coordinate. This is done by function calculateCurParameter.

Then I use this four points to calculate parameters for an linear equation:

CursorPos=m*angle+b

So you get for every new angle a new Cursor Position.

```
Private mX As Double
Private bX As Double
Private mY As Double
Private bY As Double
```

...

```
Private Sub calculateCurParameter(ByVal maxYawRight As Double, ByVal rightBorder As Double, ByVal maxYawLeft As Double, ByVal leftBorder As Double, ByVal maxPitchUp As Double, ByVal topBorder As Double, ByVal maxPitchDown As Double, ByVal bottomBorder As Double)

'this function calculates the parameter for Ycur=m*Xangle+b for each Pitch and Yaw

'calculate the parameter for the CursorPosition X
dim deltaX= maxYawLeft-maxYawRight
dim deltaY=leftBorder-rightBorder
mX=deltaY/deltaX
bX=rightBorder-mX*maxYawRight

'calculate the parameter for the CursorPosition Y
deltaX=bottomBorder-topBorder
deltaY=maxPitchDown-maxPitchUp
mY=deltaY/deltaX
bY=topBorder-mY*maxPitchUp
end Sub
```

After that calculation, I use a quadratic weighted moving average (QWMA) as a low pass filter cursor outputs calculated by the function y=m*x+b.

For that moving average I use the last 50 samples of each angle.
After that I put the two angles in each linear equation(cursorPos=m*angle+b) as described.

```
            'Timer-Event which is triggered each 8ms
        ' yaw and pitch are in degrees and are updated in this timer event before
                    Dim xCoordCur = Math.Round(mX * yaw + bX)
                    Dim yCoordCur = Math.Round(mY * pitch + bY)
                    arrayCurY(cursorCounter) = yCoordCur
                    arrayCurX(cursorCounter) = xCoordCur
                    If cursorCounter =50 Then 'need 50 samples to do the QWMA
                        Dim aqwmY = qwma_calculating(arrayCurY)'function to calculate the QWMA, seems to be working
                        Dim aqwmX = qwma_calculating(arrayCurX)
            'the mouse pointer should not leave the form    
                        If aqwmX > Panel_Right.Location.X Then
                            aqwmX = Panel_Right.Location.X
                        ElseIf aqwmX < (Panel_Left.Location.X + Panel_Left.Width) Then
                            aqwmX = Panel_Left.Location.X + Panel_Left.Width
                        End If
                        If aqwmY > Panel_Bottom.Location.Y Then
                            aqwmY = Panel_Bottom.Location.Y
                        ElseIf aqwmY < (Panel_Top.Location.Y + Panel_Top.Height) Then
                            aqwmY = Panel_Top.Location.Y + Panel_Top.Height
                        End If

            'Set the new Cursor Position
                        Cursor.Position = New Point(aqwmX, aqwmY)
                        arrayValuesMoving(arrayCurX)'function to move the values one index forward
                        arrayValuesMoving(arrayCurY)
                    Else
                        cursorCounter += 1
                    End If
```

In the my last step I set the new Cursor-Position

```
Cursor.Position=New Point(xCoor,yCoor)
```

Now I can control the mouse pointer by moving the IMU, but it is very unstable.
For example the mouse pointer still moves although the IMU doesn't move.

It's even impossible to hover over some form elements.
What did I do wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should post some actual code, because it is hard to understand what is happening from the prose description above. Especially if it is due to some coding error, rather than a logic error.

Answer (score 0):

I added the follwoing code:

```
                            If xCoor > Cursor.Position.X + 3 Or xCoor < Cursor.Position.X - 3 Then
                            istxCoor = True
                        Else
                            istxCoor = False
                        End If
                        If yCoor > Cursor.Position.Y + 3 Or yCoor < Cursor.Position.Y - 3 Then
                            istyCoor = True
                        Else
                            istyCoor = False
                        End If
                        If istxCoor And istyCoor Then
                            SetCursorPos(xCoor, yCoor)
                        ElseIf istxCoor Then
                            SetCursorPos(xCoor, Cursor.Position.Y)
                        ElseIf istyCoor Then
                            SetCursorPos(Cursor.Position.X, yCoor)
                        End If
```

it is now more steady but it has now a time lag.